# What do the Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors Of A Coefficient Matrix Tell You?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, regression, linear-regression

I see eigenvalues and eigenvectors talked about a lot in relation to a coefficient matrix (in regression and time series models).  What is the significance of eigenvalues and eigenvectors in this context and what do they tell you?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you give us a bit of background here? What exactly is meant by the "coefficient matrix" in this context? Taking the term literally, one could come to the conclusion that you're talking about the matrix $X'X$, where
$$
X = \pmatrix{1&x_1\\1&x_2\\ \vdots \\ 1&x_n},
$$
but this matrix doesn't tell you anything about the data

Comment: Perhaps you are referring to the sample covariance matrix $\pmatrix{s_{xx} & s_{xy}\\ s_{yx} & s_{yy}}$